# Mongo db Driver object when converted to string and back throws Type error: db.collection is not a function on Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to pass Mongodb driver object from one lambda function to another, to achieve this I converted mondb database object received to json and to string. but when it is converted back from string to json to mondb database object, program throws TypeError: cachedDbConn2.collection is not a function error

Sample code:

```
'use strict';

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
let cachedDbConn = null;
const password = 'password here';
const uri = "mongo url here"

let response;

exports.testFunc = async (event, context) => {
    try {
        const {
            parse,
            stringify,
            toJSON,
            fromJSON
        } = require('flatted');
       
        cachedDbConn = await connectToDatabase(uri);

        // converting object to string
        let tempConnectJson = toJSON(cachedDbConn)
        let tempConnectStr = stringify(tempConnectJson)

        // converting string back to object
        let tempConnect2Json = parse(tempConnectStr);
        let cachedDbConn2 = fromJSON(tempConnect2Json) 


        const query = { _id: "10030955"};
        const options = {},

        var listingsAndReviewss = cachedDbConn2.collection("listingsAndReviews");

        const cursor = await listingsAndReviewss.find(query, options);
        var count = await cursor.count();
        if (count === 0) {
            data = "No documents found"
        } else {
            data = await cursor.toArray();
            
        }
        
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    }
    return data
};

async function connectToDatabase(uri_in) {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(uri_in);
    cachedDbConn = client.db('sample_airbnb');
    
    return cachedDbConn;
}
```

Comment: first try to verify the behavior  toJSON function when an object has functions as its properties (it does not work as you think).  Second a JSON is not and object and you can't save functions on it. You could save the text of a function and use eval() to execute but this aproach is not a good idea... i think you should create a connection.js file, and share this file over all lambdas you need.